# Count function in Dynamic where clause of grouped records

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a dynamic where clause to filter Grouped records. I first grouped records based on a field and then based on group count I need to filter.

Something like this:

```
groups.Where("group.Count() > 2")
```

I cannot use regular where clause as I am dynamically building the condition.

How can I use count function inside this filter?

Comment: "I cannot use regular where clause as I am dynamically building the condition." - How dynamic is this really? If you can build a `Func<T, bool>` dynamically, you can then pass that to a regular Where call. What is driving the decision to filter by group count here?

Comment: Need to filter a list based on its no. of appearances in the list. This filter can be lt, gt, lte, gte or =

Comment: Okay, so you can use a switch statement to convert each of those into a suitable function. Without more context it's hard to give more concrete information, but I expect you really *can* do this without just passing code as a string into a dynamic where clause.

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing right now(using switch statement). Was trying to do it in single statement by building the query dynamically using dynamic linq.

Comment: I suspect if the degree of "being dynamic" is limited, you'll find it much simpler to build the conditions yourself. If you have decided you *definitely* want to use dynamic LINQ, please provide a [mcve] so that we can experiment - otherwise it'll be all too easy for us to come up with a solution that solves *just this bit* (perhaps just `.Where("Count() > 2")`?) but doesn't really work for you.